# SQLite out of memory error in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I found an example about sqlite with objective c and used my project. But I have a problem. when creating add statement. The error is 'out of memory' exeption. How can I fixed this error?

in viewcontroller class:

```
iDailyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iDailyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

//Create a Coffee Object.
MyClass *coffeeObj = [[MyClass alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:0];
coffeeObj.Date = dateInString;
NSDecimalNumber *temp = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:first];
coffeeObj.Latitude = temp;
NSDecimalNumber *temp2 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:second];
coffeeObj.Longitude = temp2;
[temp release];
coffeeObj.isDirty = NO;
coffeeObj.isDetailViewHydrated = YES;

//Add the object
[appDelegate addCoffee:coffeeObj];
```

sql add method:

```
- (void) addCoffee {

if(addStmt == nil) {
    const char *sql = "insert into records(Date, Latitude, Longitude) Values(?, ?, ?)";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [Date UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_double(addStmt, 2, [Latitude doubleValue] );
sqlite3_bind_double(addStmt, 3, [Longitude doubleValue] );

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
else
    //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
    RecordID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

//Reset the add statement.
sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had copied and pasted some code and I was trying to execute an SQL statement after I had closed the DB connection. I removed the erroneous line:

success = [dbHandler executeUpdate:sql];

...and it removed the out of memory error.